# Configuring LIRC on Raspberry PI for AC control

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, infrared, lirc, home-assistant

I've been working on a project of automating my Carrier 42QTD018R8S Air Conditioner in order to be able to control it from HomeAssistant IO. As I have kernel 4.19, I followed this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=235256) in order to install and configure LIRC. My AC IR remote is Carrier RG56N/BGEF. I managed to record signals using irrecord, but when i tried to send for example ON code using irsend; [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBZI4.png) is the circuit for IR transmitter. I could see the IR LED blink through my smartphone, but my AC didn't turn on. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what should I try to do in order to properly send the code to control the AC?

Answer (score 0):

transmitting IR signals with LIRC yields random patterns (recorded with a digital oscilloscope):

[lircd.conf working flawlessly on jessie utterly fails on buster - Raspberry Pi Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=281831)